# String replace everything before X

Tags: asp.net, regex, string, replace

What is the best method to replace my urls on Render.

I can have several structures of my urls in my aspx pages, depend of my folder structure like:

```
example1 - NavigateUrl="../Folder/something"
example2 - NavigateUrl="./Folder/something"
example3 - NavigateUrl="Folder/something"
```

Then i check my whole html on Render and make some Regex.Replace

```
 html = Regex.Replace(html, "src=\"([^\"]+)Folder/([^\"]+)\"", Function, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then in my function i need to make any of above urls like

```
New/Folder/anything
```

Here is my function

```
private static string FixUrlUploads(Match match)
{
    string what = match.ToString();}
```

string what can have values as example1, example2, example3 or (anything)Folder/anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to convert "(anything)Folder/anything"  to "New/Folder/anything"?, where this occurs in a `src="..."`? Or do you mean `NavigateUrl="..."` as per your examples?

```
html = Regex.Replace(html,"src=\"[^\"]*\\b(Folder/[^\"]+)\"", 
                          "src=\"New/$1\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This replaces `src="(anything)Folder/(anything2)"` with `src="New/(anything2)"`.

Comment: dont work for me, here is what i have in my html

<img id="ImageButton1" src="../Uploads/userid/image.jpg">

Tried with :

html = Regex.Replace(html, "src=\"[^\"]*\b(Upload/[^\"]+)\"",
                           "src=\"newdomain.com/$1\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: Ahh, I think I forgot about C# strings - you have to double-escape the backslash in `\b`. I'll update my answer. See the regex in action [here](http://regexr.com?2vr43)